# gatsby-source-stripe develop errors

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, gatsby

i want to gatsby stripe serverless checkout , i added products on stripe. but i cant install gatsby-source-stripe or gatsby-source-stripe-products. error;

```
error UNHANDLED EXCEPTION


  Error: /...../node_modules/gatsby-source-stripe/gatsby-node.js:4
  exports.sourceNodes = async ({ actions }, { objects = [], secretKey = "" }) =>   {
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer
```

gatsby-config

```
  {
     resolve: `gatsby-source-stripe`,
    options: {
       objects: [
        'balance',
         'customers',
       'products',
      'applicationFees',
       'skus',
         'subscriptions'
     ],
       secretKey: process.env.STRIPE_SECRET
     }
   },
```

i have .env file.

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have entered test SKUs in Stripe - you can do so by toggling the View test data.